Interpolation of IV based on delta
I have a dataset with options, all the same date and time to maturity but different IV and delta. Now, I want to find the IV for certain delta values (e.g 0.5) through interpolation. Do you think that cubic spline interpolation is an appropriate method here or is there a better way to do that?

Cubic spline is a quick and effective method to do so. It is usually fine for interpolation purposes.

It depends on the use case. If you just want a smooth curve you can use cubic splines. But if you are using the results for any pricing, splines are not sufficient since the resulting curve may contain arbitrage.

Cubic spline should work, if the relationship between IV and delta is relatively smooth and continuous. However, if there are sharp changes in the IV values as delta varies, cubic spline interpolation may not be the best approach. In such cases, interpolation methods such as linear interpolation or polynomial interpolation could be more effective.
Visually inspect the relationship between IV and delta before selecting interpolation method.

After any kind of IV interpolation, we need to make sure that the resulting vol curve/surface/cube does not admit arbitrage.
